# What's the difference between a rune and an infusion?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I don't really understand what the difference is between a rune and an infusion. The wiki for the game says:

> Inscriptions come in two flavors: runes and infusions. Runes are magical glyphs drawn on the body like temporary tattoos. Infusions are natural substances smeared/attached to the body, like nicotine patches.

That doesn't really clear it up for me. I'm assuming there is a mechanical difference and not just a thematic difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to the power source, as described in the flavor text.
Runes are arcane, and therefore suppressed by antimagic, and not usable by Zigur followers.
Infusions are natural, and cannot be used by undead characters.

Comment: But they otherwise function identically (take up an inscription slot, etc)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One more minor difference is that there are separate saturation effects for infusions and runes. The wiki has all relevant information: http://te4.org/wiki/Inscriptions